# VBA code to add multiple hyphens inside cell

Tags: excel, vba

Hello and thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide. I have many lines of data, part numbers mostly of various alpha and numeric values inside one cell.  I do this by the "alt" - "enter" method so that one cell has many lines inside this cell. I want to add a hyphen to each single data part number line within that cell.  I've searched plenty forums and vba tips, but they all seem to address removing, or adding but on a cell per cell basis.  I've also tried concatenate with no luck.
any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

e.g. Cell A1.
M23053/5-115-0 
202K142-25
M24308/2-1F
DE24657

to this....Cell A1
 - M23053/5-115-0 
 - 202K142-25
 - M24308/2-1F
 - DE24657

Comment: look at `REPLACE` function. Something like `Replace(Range("A1"),Chr(10)," - ")` * not sure if Chr(10) is carriage return.

Answer (score 0):

To add the hyphens you can an array. Something like:
    =Replace(A1,Match(False,ISERROR(1*Mid(A1,Row(INDIRECT("1:100")),1)),0),0,"-")